# Simple shell with indirect input

Tags: c, bash, shell

I am writing a simple code to implement the indirect input function for a unix/linux shell.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

extern void error(char* message);    
void
cisshRedirectedInput(char* command[], char* inputFile)
{
  //Try to implement the RedirectInput from here
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    int fd;        
//For the child process
    if ((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        //Try to input files, failing on an error
    fd=open(inputFile,O_RDONLY);//To read input file

        if(fd < 0)
        {
            error("sampleSh: error opening standard input file");
            exit(1);
        }
        //use dup() to copy file
        close(1);
        if(dup(fd) < 0)
        {
            error("sampleSh: error duplicating standard input");
            perror("dup()");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Close file and exec()
        close(fd);
        execvp(command[0], command);
        //If failure in any case
        error("sampleSh: failure to execute command");
        exit(1);
    }          
    else
    {
        /* This is the parent process.
         * Wait for the child to terminate.
         */
        if(wait(&status) < 0)
        {
            error("sampleSh: error waiting for child.");
            perror("wait");
        }

        if(status != 0)
            error("sampleSh: command exited with nonzero error status.");
    }

}
```

However, after compilation (no error reported), but when I try (fileList created already)

```
sort -r <fileList
```

The shell just stuck there without giving me answer, what is the problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard input file descriptor is 0 (or `STDIN_FILENO`), not 1 (or `STDOUT_FILENO`).

Either use:

```
int fd = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY);

if (fd < 0) …
close(0);
if (dup(fd) < 0) …
close(fd);
```

Or:

```
int fd = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY);

if (fd < 0) …
if (dup2(fd, 0) < 0) …
close(fd);
```

It is good that your code does the `close(fd)` after duplicating to a standard I/O descriptor — that is almost always correct.  It's also good that you are checking that the key system calls succeed. (There isn't much you can do if `close()` fails.)

---

This simple modification of your code (key change: use `close(0);` instead of `close(1);`) works for me.  Did you null terminate your argument list?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static inline void error(char *message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
}

void
cisshRedirectedInput(char *command[], char *inputFile);

void
cisshRedirectedInput(char *command[], char *inputFile)
{
    // Try to implement the RedirectInput from here
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    int fd;
    // For the child process
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        // Try to input files, failing on an error
        fd = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY); // To read input file

        if (fd < 0)
        {
            error("sampleSh: error opening standard input file");
            exit(1);
        }
        // use dup() to copy file
        close(0);
        if (dup(fd) < 0)
        {
            error("sampleSh: error duplicating standard input");
            perror("dup()");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Close file and exec()
        close(fd);
        execvp(command[0], command);
        // If failure in any case
        error("sampleSh: failure to execute command");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        /* This is the parent process.
         * Wait for the child to terminate.
         */
        if (wait(&status) < 0)
        {
            error("sampleSh: error waiting for child.");
            perror("wait");
        }

        if (status != 0)
            error("sampleSh: command exited with nonzero error status.");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *args[] = { "sort", "-r", 0 };
    cisshRedirectedInput(args, "fileList");
    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
bash-assoc-arrays.sh
cissh.c
fileList
kwargs.py
makefile
posixver.h
rangeinc.c
select.c
spc.py
testcsv.py
uncrustify.bug
yield.py
```

Output:

```
yield.py
uncrustify.bug
testcsv.py
spc.py
select.c
rangeinc.c
posixver.h
makefile
kwargs.py
fileList
cissh.c
bash-assoc-arrays.sh
```

Comment: Hello Jonathan, thank you very much for your reply. I fixed the errors as you pointed out. But such error still come out: "sort:fflush failed: standard output: Bad file descriptor"  "sort: write error", what is reason please?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solve everything. I just had some typo before.